# Which is the best - Using built in functions or writing my own?

Tags: php

Which one is faster and good? 
Writing own functions or using in built function in php
Eg. For converting 2D array into 1D array.
I have to use

```
array_merge($array1)
```

or writing my own function using

```
foreach(){
   }
```

Comment: Try to always use built in function, because its already written in some of  library. Also it avoids code redundancy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, the predefined PHP functions are faster. They are written in C, therefore they will be faster, no matter how you write your own PHP functions.

If you write them yourself, you have more control and power over the outcome. You have to decide whats necessary in your case.

Comment: You might also want to add that the algorithm PHP uses might be optimized. I don't say that you can't write better ones yourself, but you hopefully get the point